# Does Doctrine 2 required foreign keys to be defined?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a relational database, however, there aren't any foreign keys defined, and many of the tables are not `InnoDB`, so can't support foreign keys anyway.

I would like to start experimenting with Doctrine on this database, but there is a lot of reference to foreign keys in the documentation, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

I'm anxious about diving in and changing table storage engines to `InnoDB` and defining tons of foreign keys, because I don't want to impact performance if I don't have to.

- Does Doctrine require foreign keys to be defined in order to manage associations between entities?
- If it isn't required but optional, what features of Doctrine do I sacrifice if I don't have foreign keys defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for you to switch to InnoDB for Doctrine.

1. No.
2. I find the Doctrine's CLI tools for updating and generating the database schema will often try to generate the SQL with foreign keys. You can manually set up the database, or modify the code it generates, to avoid this.

So, **no**, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you define some  Associations mapping for your entities it may convert to foreign keys by doctrine automatically

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

i you want those foreign keys in your db too  you have to use doctrine CLI for creating your schema

for more info about using doctrine cli :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html